# SFMC Triggered Send Email - send email to changed email address on Lead in Sales Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, apexrest, sales-cloud

I am looking for second opinion on my understanding of subscriber key in SFMC.
In my environment on SFMC SK is `Lead Id`.

I am trying triggered email send from SalesCloud. The email goes good on the email address for the first time. Now when I change email address on lead and try to send email it does not go to it. I receive no error from SFMC in response, however, I also do not see anything request queued up in SFMC.

But when I send again to previous email address it goes well.

Is SFMC binding email address to subscriber key or it is its standard behavior?

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is that there is a bug in the Salesforce where changes to emailaddresses are not updated in the All Subscribers List.

In your case, the emails are still been sent to the old email address. You can verify this by :

1. Go the Subscriber
2. Select the All Subscribers List
3. Search for the contact by SubscriberKey.
4. Navigate to History

To correct this , you would have to do the following:

1. Create an Import on the lead up
2. Query email addresses that have changed and store this in a DE
3. Run a Data extract on the DE
4. Run a file Transfer activity (Moving it to the Export Folder of the FTP)
5. Run another File Transfer Activity (Moving it to the Inport Folder of the FTP)
6. Import this into the All Subscribers List

You lead email addresses should now be updated

Comment: Thanks Mate! Is this a bug in Salesforce or in Salesforce Marketing Cloud.  Moreover can all of the above steps be automated for every time an email address is changed on lead or they will have to be done manually.

Comment: Hi Nitesh, it is a marketing cloud and it can all be automated. Will update answer